# Finding the length of line-plane intersection

Tags: geometry

[image]

It is known that an ABCD.EFGH cube has a 12 cm side. If P was an intersection between two lines, BG and FC, and. Q is the intersecting point of segment EP on plane DBFH, find out the length of segment EQ.

Now I tried to make another plane, which is ACGE in an attempt to find where is Q exactly? So that's the only problem, I can't seem to find out what should I do to find the EQ. I will do the math on my own, thank you!

Comment: Can you find the equation of the plane $DBFH$ and the line $EP$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @Marco Umm, I don't think so. My teacher has only taught me to solve these three dimensions problem using triangle planes, phthagoras, projection rule, etc.

Comment: Try projecting everything down onto the $ABCD$ plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use Aretino's picture to describe it. We have to find the x,y and z coordinates of the Q point.Let's find x and y coordinate first from the EFGH face.

So,let's find $EN$ first.for that, I will work on $EFGH$ face only.considering the face as a 2D plane where $E$ is the origin.$EF$ is toward $x$ direction and $EH$ is toward $y$ direction.Now,let's find the coordinates.Here,$E(0,0),F(12,0),G(12,12),H(0,12)$.So,we notice that the equation of $FH$ line is
$$y=-x+12......(1)$$
And the equation of $EL$ line is
$$y=\dfrac{1}{2}x......(2)$$

Solving (1) and (2) we get M(8,4).
So,x and y coordinate of the Q point is 8 and 4.Now we have to calculate z coordinate.So, let's work on the face $ABEF$
The equation of line EP is

$$x+2y=24.................(3)$$
$$[\text{As, It is passing through E(0,12),P(12,6)}]$$

Emagine the line 
$$x=8..........(4)$$
So,we get (8,8)
So,the z coordinate is 8.[4 from plane EFGH]
Q(8,4,8).

These gives $$EM=\sqrt{8^2+4^2}=4\sqrt{5}$$
Hence, $$EQ=\sqrt{(4\sqrt{5})^2+4^2}=4\sqrt{6}$$

Comment: Triangles $EFL$ and $ELP$ are NOT equal.

Comment: I got it...thanks @Aretino.  I am fixing it as early as possible

Answer (score 0):

From $P$ and $Q$ drop perpendiculars $PL$ and $QM$ to the top face of the cube. In square $EFGH$ you can then easily find, by similarity, $EM=(2/3)EL$ and then, again by similarity, $EQ=(2/3)EP$. On the other hand:
$$
EP=\sqrt{EL^2+LP^2}=\sqrt{EF^2+FL^2+LP^2}=\sqrt{12^2+6^2+6^2}=6\sqrt6.
$$
Hence: $EQ=4\sqrt6$.

[image]